# Sqlite giving NullPointerException error in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to use sqlite DB to store images along with other information in my android app but i am getting this error

```
06-20 12:00:51.411    4132-4132/braindottech.com.fishid E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: braindottech.com.fishid, PID: 4132
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
        at braindottech.com.fishid.PhotoDBMS.<init>(PhotoDBMS.java:65)
        at braindottech.com.fishid.CameraScan$6.onClick(UseSqliteDB.java:23)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is my "UseSqliteDB.java" code:

```
public class UseSqliteDB extends Fragment {

  private Button saveResult;

  public UseSqliteDB(){}

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);

      context = this.getActivity();
      saveResult = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_save_CameraPreview);

      saveResult.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                PhotoDBMS photoDBMS = new PhotoDBMS(getActivity());
                String nameImage = "IMAGE";
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                nameImage += calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) + calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) +
                        calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND) + calendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
                Boolean response = photoDBMS.insertData(nameImage, resultTV.getText().toString(), finalBitmap);
                if (!response) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Database entry failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Database entry successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }catch(Exception e){
               Log.d("HIP","E = "+e);
            }

        }
      });

      return v;
  }

}
```

PhotoDBMS.java

```
public class PhotoDBMS {

  private Context context;

  public PhotoDBMS(Context c){
      context = c;
  }

  public static abstract class DBMS_Constants implements BaseColumns {
      public static final String TABLE_NAME = "MY_COLLECTION";
      public static final String COLUMN_NAME_NAME = "Name";
      public static final String COLUMN_NAME_INFO = "Info";
      public static final String COLUMN_NAME_IMAGE = "Image";
  }

  private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
  private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";
  private static final String BLOB = "BLOB";
  private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DBMS_Constants.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
        DBMS_Constants._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
        DBMS_Constants.COLUMN_NAME_NAME + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
        DBMS_Constants.COLUMN_NAME_INFO + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
        DBMS_Constants.COLUMN_NAME_IMAGE + BLOB + " )";

  private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBMS_Constants.TABLE_NAME;

  public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
      public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
      public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FeedReader.db";

      public DbHelper(Context context) {
          super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
      }
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
          db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE);
      }
      public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
        // to simply to discard the data and start over
          db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
          onCreate(db);
      }

      public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
          onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
      }

  }

  DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);
  SQLiteDatabase collectionDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

  public boolean insertData(String name, String info, Bitmap bm){

      bitmapUtility utility = new bitmapUtility();
      byte[] image =  utility.getBytes(bm);
      ContentValues cv = new  ContentValues();
      cv.put(DBMS_Constants.COLUMN_NAME_NAME,    name);
      cv.put(DBMS_Constants.COLUMN_NAME_INFO,    info);
      cv.put(DBMS_Constants.COLUMN_NAME_IMAGE, image);
      return collectionDB.insert( DBMS_Constants.TABLE_NAME, null, cv ) > 0;

  }

  public boolean deleteData(String name){
      return collectionDB.delete(DBMS_Constants.TABLE_NAME, DBMS_Constants.COLUMN_NAME_NAME + " = " + name, null) > 0;
  }

}
```

I am getting this error on try-catch section inside UseSqliteDB.java. Please help me to solve this error. Thankx in advance!

Comment: can you provide full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Move your `context = this.getActivity();` into `onActivityCreated` and pass that context like `PhotoDBMS photoDBMS = new PhotoDBMS(context);`.  Remove `dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();` from `PhotoDBMS` class if it's unnecessary.

Comment: @SripadRaj yes uploaded the logcat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is due to:

```
DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);
SQLiteDatabase collectionDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

lines added at class level instead of inside any method.

Either create a method and call it using `photoDBMS` to create and get database object:

```
public void createDB(){
    DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase collectionDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

and in Button onClick method call it :

```
PhotoDBMS photoDBMS = new PhotoDBMS(getActivity());
photoDBMS.createDB();
```

OR move both lines inside `PhotoDBMS` class constructor

Comment: Thankx @prosper K(sorry i can't write your name like you did). It is working now but now i am getting 'Boolean response' equals 'false'. Should i create another post for this issue?

Comment: @Algor7: check what `collectionDB.insert( DBMS_Constants.TABLE_NAME, null, cv )` method returning and if possible then create new question

Comment: @prosper K : It is returning -1

Comment: @Algor7: means insert query is not executed successfully

Comment: @Algor7: i think also need to change `private static final String BLOB = "BLOB";` to `private static final String BLOB = " BLOB";` mean add space before BLOB datatype as u have done for Text type

Comment: @prosper K. It says android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table MY_COLLECTION has no column named Image (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO MY_COLLECTION(Image,Info,Name) VALUES (?,?,?)  on line collectionDB.insert( DBMS_Constants.TABLE_NAME, null, cv )

Comment: @Algor7: use COMMA_SEP = " ," instead of `COMMA_SEP = ","` i think probably issue is related to spaces before column names

Answer (score 1):

**Try this,**

Replace your `PhotoDBMS` class by

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "MY_COLLECTION";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_NAME = "Name";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_INFO = "Info";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_IMAGE = "Image";
    private static final String _ID = "id";

    private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
    private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";
    private static final String BLOB = "BLOB";


    private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            COLUMN_NAME_NAME + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            COLUMN_NAME_INFO + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            COLUMN_NAME_IMAGE + BLOB + " )";

    private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;

        // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
        public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FeedReader.db";

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE);
    }
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
        // to simply to discard the data and start over
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String name, String info, Bitmap bm){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
        bitmapUtility utility = new bitmapUtility();
        byte[] image =  utility.getBytes(bm);
        ContentValues cv = new  ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME_NAME,    name);
        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME_INFO,    info);
        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME_IMAGE, image);
        return sqLiteDatabase.insert( TABLE_NAME, null, cv ) > 0;

    }

    public boolean deleteData(String name){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
        return sqLiteDatabase.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME_NAME + " = " + name, null) > 0;
    }

}
```

And `call`

```
    DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(getActivity());
    dbHelper.insertData(nameImage, resultTV.getText().toString(), finalBitmap);
```

Comment: Your answer is also appreciable. Thank you so much.